# why does std::sort not require the user to specify the templated types?

Tags: c++, templates, std

If I understand correctly, in the Standard Library, there exists this definition of [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```cpp
template< class RandomIt > 
constexpr void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

Suppose I have such a vector that I wish to sort:

```cpp
std::vector<int> data {9, 7, 5, 3, 1};
```

If this is the case, then why can I just write:

```cpp
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

as opposed to requiring:

```cpp
std::sort<std::vector<int>::iterator>(data.begin(), data.end());
```

If possible, could someone provide a generic explanation? I think I've definitely seen more than one instance of this where the template type almost seems to be automatically deduced... or is it being automatically deduced...?

Comment: It is deduced. See [Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ah I meant to mean that I observed that this was one of the definitions, I shall modify the post to clarify.

Comment: Since c++17 many standard types also have deduction guides, for example `std::vector data {9, 7, 5, 3, 1};` is allowed since c++17. The type od `data` is deduced to be `std::vector<int>` because the initializer list contains `int` elements. https://godbolt.org/z/xavvqEPfE

Comment: Considering the series of edits, I'd also recommend taking a look at [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: The implementation has visibility of the type of `data`, and therefore of the return type of `data.begin()` and `data.end()`.   From that, it is able to automatically deduce the template parameter.    And the standard specifies a set of rules so it can .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or is it being automatically deduced...?

Yes.

When a template parameter is used for a function parameter, the template argument can be deduced from the argument passed to the function. So, in this case `RandomIt` is deduced from the arguments `data.begin()` and `data.end()`.